# How to convert each of my vector strings to a epoch time date

Tags: c++

I am using a qvector to store my x values in my qcustom chart and i directly parse a json format in which my x values should be coming from a {date} value in the json format, so i store the {date} as a string but how can i convert all of the time values which are strings into epoch formats to then be represented as dates in my qcustom plot? Below is my code:

```
   //Retrieves json format of data
    Json::Value chartData = IEX::stocks::chartYtd(symbolSearchedStd);

    //Stores x and y values
    QVector<double> closePrice(365);
    QVector<string>  time(365);

    int  n = chartData.size();

    //Finds max and min for range
    float maxAvg = closePrice[0];
    float minAvg = closePrice[0];
    //Reads in data from json(historical data 1 day delayed)
    for(Json::Value::ArrayIndex i = 0 ; i != chartData.size(); i++)
    {
        if(chartData[i].isMember("close"))
        {
            if((closePrice[i] == 0) && (i != chartData.size() - 1))
            {
                closePrice[i] = closePrice[i-1];
            }

            closePrice[i] = (chartData[i]["close"].asDouble());
            time[i] = (chartData[i]["close"].asString());
        }

        if(closePrice[i] > maxAvg)
        {
            maxAvg = closePrice[i];
        }

        else if(closePrice[i] < minAvg)
        {
            minAvg = closePrice[i];
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON dates are often stored in ISO8601 (for Javascript).

Since you use Qt for your data types I think your best option is to use [QDateTime::fromString](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromString) and specify the format to [Qt::ISODate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#DateFormat-enum)

Once you got your QDateTime you can call the method [QDateTime::toSecsSinceEpoch](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toSecsSinceEpoch)

```
qint64 secsSinceEpoch = QDateTime::fromString(time[i].c_str(), Qt::ISODate).toSecsSinceEpoch();
```

Comment: Thank you I will give it a shot!